# Installing Trac to continually run

Tags: trac

I have recently added Trac to my server to work with my Git Repo.

I can get it all working fine with  `tracd --port 8000 /path/to/myproject`

But as soon as I close my Putty the site goes offline, whats the best way about getting Trac to continue running?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
nohup tracd --port 8000 /path/to/myproject &
```

?

See [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

You can then run multiple projects at once by simpling running multiple instances of tracd

```
nohup tracd --port 8000 /path/to/myproject1 &
nohup tracd --port 8001 /path/to/myproject2 &
nohup tracd --port 8002 /path/to/myproject3 &
```

And for a more correct answer about handling several projects, I redirect you to the documentation :) : 
[TracMultipleProjects/SingleEnvironment](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/SingleEnvironment)

[TracMultipleProjects/MultipleEnvironments](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/MultipleEnvironments)

Comment: thanks that does answer my question but means I can only have one project at a time

Comment: http://trac.edgewall.org Trac can have multiple projects which I am using I have got it set up to have 1 project but to be effective I need multiple which with the code I have to run only allows one

Comment: see my EDIT for a solution. I ll have a look at the doc later

Comment: thanks yeah that would work although there is a way so it will work all under the same port which would be ideal however I can not seem to work out how thanks again

Comment: Nick, if you really need multiple project under one umbrella and like Trac, look at http://incubator.apache.org/bloodhound/.  This is based off of Trac and is designed to have multiple projects.

Comment: @NickWhite: "... which with the code I have to run only allows one" - Stop, your statement isn't true, sorry. It's straight-forward from the docs and to prove that, I do point right at relevant parts in my answer. Trac is largely self-documenting (in its set of default wiki page, that comes with each Trac environment, and has a built-in search function, so you can even do without internet connection and Google & Co. Your questions show no evidence, that you tried to find the answer in available documentation before. Use more care for studying the docs, please.

Answer (score 0):

Running [Trac with another web-server](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#RunningTraconaWebServer) is pretty common, if not the standard, if performance and serving many users matters to you. Then wsgi is generally recommended as current best practice. But Apache or another full-fledged web-server might be overkill for private/small work-group use, if you don't have one already running for other purposes. Up to 5 concurrent users can still be served by tracd, and you profit from the rather small footprint of this solutions.

But OP's question sprang from a failure to deploy tracd for the task anyway. I'll follow-up on this way of serving Trac now:

The *best way to run tracd detached from the starting console* is it's deamon mode:

```
./bin/tracd -p 8000 -d /data/trac/sandbox_1.0
```

See included help for many more valuable options:

```
>$ tracd --help
Usage: tracd [options] [projenv] ...

Options:
...
  -p PORT, --port=PORT  the port number to bind to
  -r, --auto-reload     restart automatically when sources are modified
  -s, --single-env      only serve a single project without the project list
  -d, --daemonize       run in the background as a daemon
  -e PARENTDIR, --env-parent-dir=PARENTDIR
...
```

Note1: *See even more* [about running `tracd`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone) and related pages in wiki documentation at trac.egdewall.org, please.

Note2: Parent dir option allows an arbitrary number of project Trac evironment folders to get detected and run from a single instance of tracd. All just have to share a common path, means: Put them all into the same folder (your parent dir).

Note3: If you don't use the `-s` switch, tracd will display an project index page. Hint's about customizing that page are [part of the excellent wiki documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList) of the Trac project at trac.edgewall.org as well.

Comment: this doesnt answer my question about having multiple trac repo's though if I am right?

Comment: Because as a matter of fact you didn't ask that. And even worse, you're obviously not willing to read yourself, because you can find that answer in the tracd help page and trac.edgewall.org wiki docs as well. I'll edit my answer now, but really consider to RTFM first before asking, ok?

Comment: @JosefAssad: Because dismissing the shell into background (another answer here) is suboptimal and rather a hack, since tracd is able to cleanly detach from the starting console with daemon mode switch (-d). And because this is the recommended way, if all of you would care for the authoritative documentation of Trac core developers. Honestly, you'll find it all there without needing to guess or read source code, no secret knowledge at all.

Comment: Please point to where the trac docs recommend using the built in server. I am familiar with trac docs and I don't see it. I don't see why you dismiss running trac under apache as being inferior.

Comment: Seems like you did entirely misunderstand my statements. Sure, use of tracd is neither encouraged nor recommended in general. But IMHO the OP did initially just ask about a way to run Trac "better", and his starting point was tracd. I didn't even touch the subject "alternative web-server" here, so can hardly have dismiss Apache applications. Where did you read that? (Read above: "The best way to run tracd ...") As a matter of fact the're pretty common for more heavily used Trac applications. Feel free to suggest to run with an "real" web-server instead.

Comment: @JosefAssad: Hope, my intention is clearer now, and is saves me from further bashing for things I've never intended, nor expressively written about.

Answer (score 0):

Check `tracd` options using `tracd --help`. There you will find a line which states:

`-d, --daemonize       run in the background as a daemon`

Voila.